# Strapi Pivot Table

Tags: strapi

new Strapi user here. Very familiar with relational DBs and relationships but not sure how to model this with Strapi.

I have a `Player` and `Poll` model. Each poll will have a question and then you can "vote" for a player.

Normally, this would be a pivot table with the following fields.

- ID
- Poll ID
- Player ID
- Votes (int that gets incremented every time the player is voted for)

I'm not sure of a good way to do this with Strapi.

Currently, I created that table manually but I'm not sure if there's an easier or better way.

Thanks!